# Get Jqgrid Column checkbox cheked value using MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to implement one good looking Grid in MVC4+Razor. Till now I have done by using jqgrid. Since I am new to jQuery grid, can someone suggest how to get checked checkbox value in column of checkbox of some id? Can someone help me how I can get that checkbox checked values in jgrid? I am attaching my HTML and Javascript code. So please send me solution using sample code.

Javascript code:

```
  (function ($) {
    $('#JQGrid1').jqGrid({

        url: '/ExamForm/GetSubjects/',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'GET',
        width: 950,
        height: 150,
        colNames:['SubjectID', 'SubjectName', 'GroupName', ' SubjectCode'],
        colModel:[
                 {name: "SubjectID", width: 70, align: "center",
                 formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false},
                 edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "No"},
                 stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], 
                     value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" },key:true },
                 { name: 'SubjectName', index: 'SubjectName', width: 60 },
                 {
                     name: 'GroupName', index: 'GroupName', width: 60, editable: true,
                     editrules: {
                         required: true,
                         edithidden: true
                     },
                     hidden: true
                 },
                 { name: 'SubjectUniversityCode', index: 'SubjectUniversityCode', width: 20 }
        ],
         rowNum: 100,
        //loadonce: true,
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['GroupName']

        },
        multiselect: true
    });



})(jQuery);
```

Get Selected row i have use following function

```
      function getSelectedRows() {

          var grid = $("#JQGrid1");
          var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");

          if (!rowKey)
              alert("No rows are selected");
          else {
              var selectedIDs = grid.getGridParam("selarrrow");
              var result = "";
              for (var i = 0; i < selectedIDs.length; i++) {
                  result += selectedIDs[i] + ",";
              }

              alert(result);
          }
           });
```